# Onsen UI 2 with React and PhoneGap development environment

Tags: reactjs, cordova, phonegap, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

I want to develop a hybrid mobile app based on Onsen UI 2, and have selected React as the framework for it.

I'm also using the PhoneGap Build service to create the app files for Android and iOS.

I am having some difficulties understanding how I can get Onsen, React and the PhoneGap CLI to work in harmony in my development environment.

How I did it for now:

I tried downloading some Onsen & React 'hello world' apps to play around with, and I got to the point, where I managed to **build** the **Onsen/Webpack/React-Hot-Reloading-Example** and put the **bundle.js** file in a new/empty PhoneGap project.

From this, I can understand that I need to separately build the react app, and then copy the bundled app into the PhoneGap app folder.

This seems like a little hassle... shouldn't there be an easier way?

Comment: Yes, there is, it's called `ReactNative` https://facebook.github.io/react-native/ . With this framework you can now build a real mobile app, not a hybrid one. It's very interesting and easy to use. I would recommend you to give a try.

Comment: Thanks Ionut, I'll have a look at it! The thing is, that we have a hybrid app in Onsen UI 1 + AngularJS 1, that we also wanted to convert to use Onsen 2 + React...